# Forcing devs to explicitly define keys for configuration data

Tags: java, configuration, enums, configuration-files

We are working in a project with multiple developers and currently the retrieval of values from a configuration file is somewhat "wild west":

- Everybody uses some string to retrieve a value from the Config object
- Those keys are spread across multiple classes and packages
- Sometimes the are not even declared as constants
- Naming of the keys is inconsistent and the config file (.properties) looks messy

I would like to sort that out and force everyone to explicitly define their configuration keys. Ideally in one place to streamline how config keys actually look.

I was thingking of using an Enum as a key and turning my retrieval method into:

```
getConfigValue(String key)
```

into something like

```
getConfigValue(ConfigKey)
```

NOTE: I am using this approach since the Preferences API seems a bit overkill to me plus I would actually like to have the configuration in a simple file.

What are the cons of this approach?

Answer (score 1):

First off, FWIW, I think it's a good idea. But you did specifically ask what the "cons" are, so:

The biggest "con" is that it ties any class that needs to use configuration data to the `ConfigKey` class. Adding a config key used to mean adding a string to the code you were working on; now it means adding to the `enum` *and* to the code you were working on. This is (marginally) more work.

You're probably not markedly increasing inter-dependence otherwise, since I assume the class that `getConfigValue` is part of is the one on which you'd define the `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

The other downside to consolidation is if you have multiple projects on different parts of the same code base.  When you develop, you have to deal with delivery dependencies, which can be a PITA.

Say Project A and Project B are scheduled to get released in that order.  Suddenly political forces change in the 9th hour and you have to deliver B before A.  Do you repackage the config to deal with it?  Can your QA cycles deal with repackaging or does it force a reset in their timeline.

Typical release issues, but just one more thing you have to manage.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it is clear that you intend to write a wrapper class for the raw Java Properties API, with the intention that your wrapper class provides a better API. I think that is a good approach, but I'd like to suggest some things that I think will improve your wrapper API.

My first suggested improvement is that an operation that retrieves a configuration value should take two parameters rather than one, and be implemented as shown in the following pseudocode:

```
class Configuration {
    public String getString(String namespace, String localName) {
        return properties.getProperty(namespace + "." + localName);
    }
}
```

You can then encourage each developer to define a string constant value to denote the *namespace* for whatever class/module/component they are developing. As long as each developer (somehow) chooses a different string constant for their namespace, you will avoid accidental name clashes and promote a somewhat organised collection of property names.

My second suggested improvement is that your wrapper class should provide type-safe access to property values. For example, provide `getString()`, but also provide methods with names such as `getInt()`, `getBoolean()`, `getDouble()` and `getStringList()`. The `int/boolean/double` variants should retrieve the property value as a string, attempt to parse it into the appropriate type, and throw a descriptive error message if that fails. The `getStringList()` method should retrieve the property value as a string and then split it into a list of strings based on using, say, a comma as a separator. Doing this will provide a consistent way for developers to get a list value.

My third suggested improvement is that your wrapper class should provide some *additional* methods such as:

```
int getDurationMilliseconds(String namespace, String localName);
int getDurationSeconds(String namespace, String localName);
int getMemorySizeBytes(String namespace, String localName);
int getMemorySizeKB(String namespace, String localName);
int getMemorySizeMB(String namespace, String localName);
```

Here are some examples of their intended use:

```
cacheSize = cfg.getMemorySizeBytes(MY_NAMSPACE, "cache_size");
timeout = cfg.getDurationMilliseconds(MY_NAMSPACE, "cache_timeout");
```

The `getMemorySizeBytes()` method should convert string values such as `"2048 bytes"` or `"32MB"` into the appropriate number of bytes, and `getMemorySizeKB()` does something similar but returns the specified size in terms of KB rather than bytes. Likewise, the `getDuration<units>()` methods should be able to handle string values like `"500 milliseconds"`, `"2.5 minutes"`, `"3 hours"` and `"infinite"` (which is converted into, say, `-1`).

Some people may think that the above suggestions have nothing to do with the question that was asked. Actually, they do, but in a sneaky sort of way. The above suggestions will result in a configuration API that developers will find to be much easier to use than the "raw" Java Properties API. They will use it to obtain that ease-of-use benefit. But using the API will have the side effect of forcing the developers to adopt a namespace convention, which will help to solve the problem that *you* are interested in addressing.

Or to look at it another way, the main con of the approach described in the question is that it offers a win-lose situation: *you win* (by imposing a property-naming convention on developers), but *developers lose* because they swap the familiar Java Properties API for another API that doesn't offer them any benefits. In contrast, the improvements I have suggested are intended to provide a win-win situation.

Comment: I agree with you on the addition of methods for typesafe retrieval. One downside I see with the two-string argument approach is: where do the namespaces come from where are they defined? If at all I would make it two enums. One for the namespace and one for the key. Right now, I think one enum will do. Thanks for the long answer! I appreciate the time you put into it.

Comment: If an application consists of N modules, and each module requires M properties, then that is N*M properties in total. Agreeing on string constants for each of those property names is a bureaucratic task that nobody will enjoy. The benefit of using two string parameters is that people need to agree only on a unique namespace name for each of the N modules, so the scope of the bureaucracy is reduced considerably. Responsibility for avoiding name clashes within a namespace can be delegated to the developers of each module. If devs for one module screw up, at least they don't impact other modules.